# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, datetime, datetime-format

I'm getting the above error when we build our *Xamarin* app from our **Azure DevOps** build pipeline.

Our *Xamarin* app consumes an **ASP.NET Web API** service that receives a date as a parameter. The date is passed as a serialised string. The service uses the **DateTime.Parse()** function to convert the string back into a *DateTime* as follows.

```
CultureInfo cultureinfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse(strstartdate, cultureinfo);
```

I want all our dates to be in GB format as that is how they are processed and stored.

The unit tests all pass when they invoke the service locally from our dev machines. But then they fail when executed from **Azure DevOps**. I suspect that **Azure DevOps** is sending the dates as US format which then break when the **DateTime.Parse()** function tries to convert them.

How do I get round this problem? I want **Azure DevOps** to send the dates as GB format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) for the Unit Tests project to be `en-GB`.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Comment: Let me give that a try and see how I get on